# SELECT row with same date value in tableA and category=1

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the `item_name` which is sold during the current day and the `category=1`

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT item_name FROM item_out_tbl io 
    WHERE item_id=sa.item_id AND category_id=1) AS item_name, 
    date_sold 
FROM sales_tbl sa
WHERE date_sold >= CURDATE();
```

after running this query, I get a

```
item_name   |   date_sold
--------------------------
   NULL     |  2015-03-29 05:16:15
  phone-ax2 |  2015-03-29 05:17:10
```

I only expect the phone-ax2 to return since `item_out_tbl` has only phone-ax2 in `category_id=1` . How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `Correlated sub-query` to `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT 
    io.item_name, 
    date_sold 
FROM sales_tbl sa
INNER JOIN item_out_tbl io 
ON item_id=sa.item_id 
WHERE sa.date_sold >= CURDATE()
AND io.category_id=1
```